# Unable to see completed view layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am creating a vertical LinearLayout that will be displayed in a vertical ScrollView.  I can't find a way in Android Studio to see the portion of the LinearLayout that is below the bottom of the ScrollView.  Is there any way to see the full layout rather than constraining it to the viewport provided by the renderer?

Answer (score 67):

Like Drew said, creating a user defined device definition has been the only solution which worked for me. Below i show you the steps to follow:

Step 1)
Within the preview-pane, open the **Virtual Device Selection** drop-down and select **Add Device Definition..**

[image]

Step 2)
Within the **Your Virtual Devices** dialog click the **Create Virtual Device** button.

[image]

Step 3)
Within the **Select Hardware** dialog click the **New Hardware Profile** button.

[image]

Step 4)
Within the **Configure Hardware Profile** dialog specify (f.e.) a **Resolution** of 720 x 4000 px and a **Screensize** of 12 inch. Also setting the Screensize results in a **density** of **xhdpi** (thanks to Mete).

[image]

Step 5) Close all dialogs and restart Android Studio.
Step 6) Open the **Virtual Device Selection** drop-down. The new user defined hardware profile can be found under **Generic Phones and Tablets**.
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer with all images and helpful descriptions

Comment: can't see any place to add height

Answer (score 37):

I've just discovered how.  You need to create a user defined device definition in Android AVD - I created one that was 480 x 4000 pixels.  Exit and restart Android Studio and then you can select this device in the preview renderer and can see 4000 pixels worth of LinearLayout.

Comment: +1 as I did not have take apart my view and for stating the need for the restart.

Comment: This is the only suitable solution i have found thus far. There is one problem; Android Studio, when using this resolution, automatically sets the density to xxxhdpi. Is there a way to set the density back to hdpi? I am using Android Studio v1.2

Comment: @Brabbeldas when you create the profile, you can give the width and height in pixels, but you can also give the "Screensize" in inches, and the combination of these settings sets the density. For example I set mine to 480x4000 with a screensize of 16 inches and this gives me hdpi

Comment: I have added a new answer with screenshots describing how to create the user defined device definition. @Drew, if you find it useful for others, you can accept is as the correct answer.

Comment: Wonderful!
For me resizing once didn't work! And the bellow answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/31582758/1752988
Also was helpful!

Answer (score 31):

**Found a easier solution**, in your `layout` add something like below and adjust as you need:

```xml
android:layout_marginTop="-1500dp"
```

Comment: Best answer, but it would be better if you use: tools:layout_marginTop="-1500dp".

This way the negative scroll only applies to the layout editor and not in runtime.

Comment: Useful when button mentioned by @Eric is not available.

Answer (score 19):

in new version of android studio (i don't know from which version, but i'm using latest 2.3.3 now) you can resize your preview layout by drag it

[image]

Comment: +1 worked for me, but had to change the device in the above gif from nexus 4 to "Custom" manually for the drag button to show.

Answer (score 17):

Android Studio will offer a toggleable full view, if the ScrollView is the root of the layout. I had put mine on top of the default RelativeLayout and had to manually fix that in the XML before the GUI would give me the full view.

Comment: How do you find this?

Comment: @MattSzaro I don't remember where I found the information, but if you mean where to find the XML to change it so the scrollview is the root item, there are two tabs at the bottom when you open the .xml for a view: "Design", and "Text". Click "Text". If you mean where to find the toggle once you have made the change, I think you need to close and reopen the project once (maybe) and then in "Design" it's the leftmost button in the second row of the toolbar, with an icon that looks a three column piece of paper or something: "Toggle Viewport Render Mode".

Comment: @davidgro, locating the option in the toolbar is what I was looking for. Thank you! This really helped.

Comment: Combined with the technique in "[Re-using Layouts with `<include/>`](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts.html)", we can extract a `ScrollView` in the middle of a layout to a separate XML file and view it in full.

Comment: What if your scrollview is not the root view. Wish they would expand the whole bloody thing and just put an outline of the the phone screen over the top to show the viewable area.

Comment: This is something google needs to look into, Why not just detect any scroll view and then make it scroll-able.

Answer (score 17):

I hope the screenshot help you :

[image: screenshot]

Comment: missing this button when i click on my scrollView on the Component Tree

Comment: Just found that scrollview must be the top layer in order to show the button. Thx Eric !

Comment: The full view Option solves my problem for vertical scroll views, however I have an embedded Horizontal scrollview that is still only partially visible, (the rest extend to the right out of view) 
Is there a way to solve this without using the Custom device option?

Comment: This is the perfect answer. it is better than the very height device profile. and is available in android studio 0.1.7+

Answer (score 13):

You can use scrollY attribute to scroll the ScrollView in the preview. Using scrollY attribute with tools namespace will only scroll the view in the display and not in the actual app. And make sure you use px as the unit with scrollY attribute.

```
tools:scrollY="150px"
```

Answer (score 5):

**Update:** Now you can scroll a ScrollView directly inside preview panel
(I tested on Android studio version 2.3.2)

Short answer: **Right click on your ScrollView and select Refactor > Extract > Layout**.

Android-studio will extract your ScrollView into a new layout file and put `tools:showIn="@layout/original_layout_file"` attribute at root layout(your ScrollView).

Note: Android-studio will preview full layout if root layout is ScrollView.

Comment: @Tequilaman If your are using Android studio version 2.3.2 you can scrolling ScrollView's content by using a mouse wheel on preview panel

Answer (score 4):

In Android Studio version 3.2.1 you can select "Custom" device on preview panel and then resize preview to whatever height you need.

[image: android studio custom preview example]

Comment: this is the easiest way! best.

Answer (score 2):

- click on the scrollView in conponent tree (on the right)
- click on the new button wich appears on the left (second row of toolbar)

Comment: could you add a screenshot? i can not see any new button appear.

Comment: @Brabbeldas the new button called "toggle viewport render mode" .maybe help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/30443662/1323374

Answer (score 1):

Another quick alternative solution is to hide the layouts temporarily at the top so that the layouts at the bottom can appear in the visible window in Android Studio.

Put `android:visibility="gone"` on the layouts that you want to hide.

Example:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/hsv02"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/ll24"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll199">

 </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: This is a very uncomfortable solution... Don't do this at least is extremely necessary.

Comment: Use `tools:visibility="gone"`.

Answer (score 0):

I might be late but it'll be a lot easier for you to just set the margins to negative to shift the scroll view to the left.

**For example:**

margin:

left: -100px

Now you can see and edit the scrollview however you like!

Answer (score 0):

TABLE LAYOUT

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow android:padding="5dip">
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="New Product Form"
            android:typeface="serif"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:textSize="20dip" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Code:"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/prod_code"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1"/>
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Name:"
            android:layout_column="0"/>
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/prod_name"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Product Price:" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/prod_price"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/add_button"
            android:text="Add Product"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancel_button"
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
















GridLAYOUT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:columnCount="3"
    android:rowCount="2"
    tools:context=".Main3Activity" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Button"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_column="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_vertical"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_rowSpan="2"
        android:text="Button" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_column="0"
        android:layout_columnSpan="2"
        android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:text="Button" />
</GridLayout>





ANOTHER TABLE LAYOUT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    tools:context="com.example.dhanya.uitablelayout.MainActivity">
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:text="Time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <TextClock
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/textClock"
            android:layout_column="1" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="First Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <EditText
            android:width="200px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <TextView
            android:text="Last Name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="0" />
        <EditText
            android:width="100px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <RatingBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
            android:layout_column="0" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Submit"
            android:layout_span="2"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_column="0" />
    </TableRow>
</android.widget.TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

The best I found is to set the device to custom. Then we can change the layout simply by dragging.

Answer (score 0):

**My layout is long and need to scroll layout even using the vertical long resolution** and when I set the layout editor to high resolutions, the screen does not scroll completely and smoothly

By setting the layout to
***3.2_HVGA_slider_ADP1_API_27***, the screen scrolled and my problem was solved