# Android studio preview for scrollView subsclass issue

Tags: android, android-studio

I have very high view. When I put it in ScrollView then Android Studio renders it correct. 
When I put my view to ScrollView subclass then Android Studio displays only top part of my view.
Subclass code: https://github.com/makovkastar/FloatingActionButton/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/melnykov/fab/ObservableScrollView.java

How looks my view in ScrollView:

[image: scrollView preview]

How looks my view in subclass of ScrollView:
[image: subclass of scrollView preview]

I use Android studio 1.2 and api 19 for rendering (for api 21 customView just throws NPE)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to see completed view layout in Android Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565388/unable-to-see-completed-view-layout-in-android-studio)