# View entire layout in Android Studio IDE

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

Is it possible to view the entire layout in design view of Android Studio? My layout's height is longer than the height of the device and I need to "scroll down" to see/edit the components but as far as I can tell it's not possible.[image]

Comment: As a workaround, switch to a preview of a larger-screened device.

Comment: I believe that is the layout. You should wrap that is in a `ScrollView`. Have you considered using a `ListView` or `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @CommonsWare, yes, I'm aware of that workaround... Curious if there was less a hacky way.

Comment: @JaredBurrows, you're misunderstanding my question.

Comment: @bwoogie I know you are talking about Android Studio. Have you actually ran this on a device? It will look just like that. So you will need to wrap that in a `ScrollView`.

Comment: @JaredBurrows This isnt about the device. this is strictly in the IDE. You can't scroll a scrollview (at least to my knowledge) in the IDE. also the screenshot is obviously not my actual project.

Comment: I know, I am just making a suggestion when you actually use this on a device is all.

Comment: i have the same issue.  Seems kind of lame to have to run the app just to get to the part where the scroller is so I can scroll up the view and see the view below the IDE frame.  I've been doing that with a part of the app that is fairly deep into the app and requires a lot of user interaction to get to.  Very long process that would have been easier with an IDE that lets you see the whole layout...all that to see if the textsize I did fits.  Nice.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565388/unable-to-see-completed-view-layout-in-android-studio