# See all of ScrollView in Android Studio Layout editor?

Tags: android, android-studio

On the left screen is how it looks right now in Android studio layout editor. Its a constraintlayout inside a scrollview which takes up the whole screen. I want the layout editor screen to expand vertically so that I can see and fit the "pink" views  too. Is it possible/how to expand vertically?

[image]

Comment: Preview a device with a taller screen

Comment: It's just draw compiled classes to canvas. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565388/unable-to-see-completed-view-layout-in-android-studio)